# Find the value of: $\frac{\sqrt{45} + \sqrt{18}} {\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{10}}}$

Tags: contest-math, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

> > Find the value of:$$\frac{\sqrt{45} + \sqrt{18}} {\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{10}}}$$

I need help solving this question. Every reply is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have:

> > $$\frac{\sqrt{45} + \sqrt{18}} {\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{10}}}$$
> >
> > ---

Then we will square the fraction:
$$ = \sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt{45}+\sqrt{18})^2} {(\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{10}})^2}}$$

---

Finish the squares:
$$=\sqrt{\frac{45+18\sqrt{10} + 18} {7+2\sqrt{10}}}$$

---

Simplify:
$$=\sqrt{\frac{63+18\sqrt{10}} {7+2\sqrt{10}}}$$

---

Factor:
$$\sqrt{\frac{9(7+2\sqrt{10})} {7+2\sqrt{10}}}$$

---

Crossing Out:
$$\sqrt{9}$$

---

Which is equal to:

> > $$\sqrt{9} = 3$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

$$\frac{\sqrt{45} + \sqrt{18}} {\sqrt{7+2\sqrt{10}}} = \frac{3 \sqrt{5}+3\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt{5}\right)^2+2\,\sqrt{2}\sqrt{5}}}$$

Comment: Wish the downvoter had left a comment why.

Comment: Nice Hint.  (+1).  And who are these nefarious down voters?

Comment: @dxiv \ Don't worry about it, man. There are people in this world who pride themselves on being walking, talking toothaches.